# Scala curried functions appear to not work with JDBC connections

Tags: scala, jdbc, inline, currying, partially-applied-type

I have an ETL framework I wrote in Scala, and in the name of removing the same try/catch and closing statements for every SQL query and update I perform, I made this trait that I mixin to all my SQL connections.

```
trait SqlConnection {

  private val defaultHandling = (stmt: PreparedStatement) => stmt.executeUpdate()
  protected val con: java.sql.Connection

  final def executeSimpleUpdate(sql: String): Unit = executeUpdate(sql)(defaultHandling)

  final def executeUpdate[T](sql: String)(statementHandling: PreparedStatement => T) = {
    val stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql)
    try { statementHandling(stmt) } finally { if (!stmt.isClosed) stmt.close() }
  }

  final def executeQuery[T](sql: String)(resultHandling: ResultSet => T) = {
    val stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql)
    try {
      val rs = stmt.executeQuery()
      try { resultHandling(rs) } finally { if (!rs.isClosed) rs.close() }
    } finally { if (!stmt.isClosed) stmt.close() }
  }

  final def close() = con.close()

}
```

However, when I run it, none of the commands get executed. I added `println`s to try to isolate what lines or code were or weren't getting run, and that gave me this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1015)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:920)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.throwConnectionClosedException(ConnectionImpl.java:1320)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:1312)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4547)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4512)
    at util.SqlConnection$class.executeQuery(Connection.scala:50)
```

I assume my problem here is misunderstanding how Scala handles function values and when the functions get executed.

Can anyone explain what is happening here or what a similar solution would be? Maybe use inlining?

Comment: There is not enough info here to solve your issue. How and where is the connection being opened?  It's clear that by the time `prepareStatement` is called on the connection that it's already been closed so you need to figure out how that happened. If the connection is being shared elsewhere (which would not be a good idea) is that other code closing it?

Comment: This wasn't your question, but note that closing a `Statement` closes the `ResultSet`, so if you know that you're closing the `Statement`, you don't need to close the `ResultSet` separately. Also, I don't see any way to pass parameters to queries through your wrapper class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't keep your connection as a field in your class. Wrap your database operations in a function that opens and closes the connection for you. Try this:

```
private def withConnection[A](f: Connection => A): A = {
   val con = JDBC.giveMeAConnection()// Do whatever you want to open a connection
   val result = f(con)
   con.close()
   result
}

final def executeQuery[T](sql: String)(resultHandling: ResultSet => T) = withConnection { conn =>
   // Use conn as you wish here.
}
```

Comment: I actually solved it and it was something completely unrelated, but thanks for the input.

Comment: @EricHartsuyker good to hear. Even so, it's better style to treat your database access this way.